# ActionFunction doesn't rerender output panel

Tags: apex, visualforce, rerender

I've got a basic page, with a custom `select` (in order to show `title` text), wrapped in an `apex:outputPanel`. Whenever I try to change the input, its `onchange` fires, puts the right value into my `selectedValue` variable, and then sets the controller's record field.

However - the information on the page stays exactly the same. Its supposed to refresh and show some help text, but doesn't show anything different.

```
<apex:actionFunction action="{!SetValue}" reRender="fieldName" immediate="true" name="SetValue">
    <apex:param assignTo="{!SelectedValue}" id="fieldName" value="" name="SelectedValue" />
</apex:actionFunction>


<apex:pageBlockSectionItem helpText="">
    <apex:outputLabel >Field</apex:outputLabel>
    <apex:outputPanel id="fieldName" >
        <!-- custom field --> 
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the `id` in the `apex:param`? `id="fieldName"`? Its the same id as the `outputPanel` - `id="fieldName"`. Removing the id from the `param` causes the `outputPanel` to refresh.

My guess is that apex was trying to rerender the `param` due to the duplicate id. You aren't supposed to be able to re-use ids - if you try to put a duplicate id anywhere else it gives you an error - but not if you use it in your `param`.

This `actionFunction` works totally fine.

```
<apex:actionFunction action="{!SetValue}" reRender="fieldName" immediate="true" name="SetValue">
    <apex:param assignTo="{!SelectedValue}" value="" />
</apex:actionFunction>
```

Comment: Couldn't find anything about this error anywhere else. Lesson from this - don't give your `param` an id.